# Should I add @JvmSuppressWildcards when injecting map object in dagger-hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Studying hilt @IntoMap annotation,
I have one problem.
When I inject this Map Object,

```
class NotificationManager @Inject constructor(
    private val notificationHandlers: Map<String, NotificationHandler>
)
```

I have to add this annotation *@JvmSuppressWildcards*
If I don't, I get this error

```
 error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.String,? extends...
```

There is no wildcard for NotificationHandler but I don't understand Why I add this @JvmSuppressWildcards.
Should I add the @JvmSuppressWildcards when injecting with Map object?

the whole code

```
interface NotificationHandler {
    fun handleNotification(notification: Notification)
}

class EmailNotificationHandler @Inject constructor() : NotificationHandler {
    override fun handleNotification(notification: Notification) {
        Timber.d("Email Notification")
    }
}

class SMSNotificationHandler @Inject constructor() : NotificationHandler {
    override fun handleNotification(notification: Notification) {
        Timber.d("SMS Notification")
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NotificationModule {

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey("email")
    fun provideEmailNotificationHandler(handler: EmailNotificationHandler): NotificationHandler {
        return handler
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey("sms")
    fun provideSMSNotificationHandler(handler: SMSNotificationHandler): NotificationHandler {
        return handler
    }
}

class NotificationManager @Inject constructor(
    private val notificationHandlers: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards NotificationHandler>
) {
    fun handleNotification(type: String, notification: Notification) {
        val handler = notificationHandlers[type]
        handler?.handleNotification(notification)
    }
}

data class Notification(val type: String, val message: String)
```